# Keeping a GeoServer image mosaic layer current as new geoTIFFs are added to the filesystem

Tags: postgis, geoserver, image-mosaic, geoserver-rest-api

I have an ImageMosaic layer with the time dimension enabled in GeoServer 2.8.x using postgres/postgis as the index store.  The system is running CentOS 7, and both GeoServer (jetty variant) and the database are on the same host.  The directory containing the geoTIFFs for the layer is kept current by rsync running on the server producing the geoTIFFs, and we are keeping the last 10 images.  I have been trying to find a way to keep the index info in the database current as images are added to/deleted from the directory.

Using the REST API seems like an option, and maybe one of, or the only option to do so.  While testing, I was able to delete all indexes from the database table using the DELETE HTTP method, but not recreate them; reharvest?  I think my biggest hurdle is just understanding the REST API.

Right now, at least, the less elegant method of recreating the entire granule index is fine.  Since I think some of the non-specific to my setup info is throwing me from the posts I found... I'm working with a layer called baserefl-loop.  I was able to list the granules using:

```
curl -v -u user:pass -XGET http://localhost:8180/geoserver/rest/workspaces/Sonalysts/coveragestores/ \
radar-baserefl-loop/coverages/baserefl-loop/index/granules.xml
```

Hopefully this is just something simple that I'm missing.

Comment: Just add a row to the index for the new image

Comment: So more of a script that would have to add/removed rows from the table as the directory is updated, not a GeoServer specific process?

Comment: its been a few years since I did this but I think that's how I did it